# How do I design a Gherkin/SpecFlow/Selenium solution to have easily parametrizable logins

Tags: selenium, cucumber, nunit, specflow, gherkin

I am developing a solution for validation of exams developed on top of a web software. This implies that:

1. Multiple users, each with separate logins and tenants, will implement an application to match exam standards
2. The exam proctor will have to run a validator that checks the implemented application against the definition of what is correct for each step (i.e. in a given step, the unit price times the ordered quantity is the dollar amount to be ordered).
3. The validator should give exact reports of what occurred so the exam can be rated.

For this, we decided to implement a stack using Selenium for browser automation, and SpecFlow/Gherkin/Cucumber to interact with Selenium.

Right now the main issue I'm having is how to have the person who administers the exam successfully and easily validate, for 20 students, that their exam is correct. My current way of running things is having an NUnit console runner being invoked by a powershell script that then uses SpecFlow to create a detailed execution report.

Should my powershell script go edit the feature files with tables containing the logins for each of the students, obtained from a .csv or something? Is there any way I can pass the csv file to NUnit so it can be used in the tests?

Thanks,
JM

Comment: Do you want to execute the whole suite of scenarios with the same login or only parts?

Comment: I can work with either, really. The option could exist for a single exam to need multiple logins to be validated, but that could be handled by different columns in a table; e.g. ApproverEmail, ApproverPassword, UserEmail, UserPassword, if it's easier / more logical to pass the context between the scenarios.

Comment: In that case, I would put the login information into the app.config. Before you start the test run, change the values for that run. In the steps then you read the values from it.

Comment: If you want, have a look at the SpecFlow+Runner (http://specflow.org/plus/runner/). It can perform a config transformation and you can define multiple targets for the whole scenario suite. An example about this is here: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow.Plus.Examples/tree/master/SeleniumWebTest ; In your case the browser information are your login information.

Comment: Hello @AndreasWillich, can you submit your answer as an answer instead of a comment, so I can accept it? I am probably going to use a separate file instead of the app.config, but I will use a similar logic, so you should have the credit.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put the login information into the app.config or another file. Before you start the test run, change the values for that run. In the steps then you read the values from it.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with all the responses provided earlier. However, if you dont want to do any of those, you can set an environment variable with the patient login key (or even the credentials) and save login+password in a file, Database or even a csv. At runtime, you will just need to read this key and insert whatever logic you want. This will work well even on non windows, build machines etc